# How to find and replace string include special character with sed command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed

I have a file with content like this:
deployment.yml

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: atl-lead
    image: "registry.it.zone/api/dev/atl-x:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-110"
    imagePullPolicy: Always
```

I want to use `sed` command to change this file to:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: atl-lead
    image: "registry.it.zone/api/dev/atl-x:1.8.0"
    imagePullPolicy: Always
```

I use command below

```
sed -i "/registry.vn.eit.zone/open-api/dev/atl-x:.*/registry.vn.eit.zone/open-api/dev/atl-x:1.8.0/g" deployment-canary.yml
```

But it shows this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unknown command: `o'
```

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always escape special symbols to avoid them being treated as regex by prefixing them with a backslash `\`

In this case it is not necessary, you could simply change the delimiter that `sed` uses from `/` to for example `%` or `!` or any other single byte character.

Instead of writing `sed 's/search/replace/'` you can simply write `sed 's%search%replace%'`.

### Example:

```
╰─$ echo 'image: "registry.it.zone/api/dev/atl-x:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-110"' | sed 's%image: "registry.it.zone/api/dev/atl-x:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-110"%image: "registry.it.zone/api/dev/atl-x:1.8.0"%'

image: "registry.it.zone/api/dev/atl-x:1.8.0"
```

**Tipp:**
Check out [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) if you have problems to create a working regular expression. It will show you each match and error as you type.

Comment: thank you @mashuptwice